# Is 2 ethyl 3 methyl oxirane optically active?

Tags: chirality

According to me this molecule does not have any any plane of symmetry nor centre of symmetry, but in my textbook it is given that this is optically inactive.
[image]

Comment: Then your textbook is wrong. Or maybe they mean a racemic mixture.

Comment: Please provide a reference for your textbook and some context. Also, the name in title doesn't match the structure (which is 2-ethyl-3-methyloxirane).

Comment: I am sorry, I have edited it. Thanks!
It was a question in the book "Advanced Problems in Organic Chemistry for JEE"
By Himanshu Pandey

Comment: You may draw the structure in a chemistry-aware search engine like [Chemspider](https://www.chemspider.com/).  With title structure _as sketched_, omitting stereochemical information like [here](https://www.chemspider.com/Search.aspx?rid=577275bf-c4fc-48c0-b2be-0ed8c1122fd4) you see there is discern about the stereogenic centres to be either in _RR_, _RS_, or _SS_ configuration.  [One](https://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.454072.html?rid=40f7ba85-af04-4252-b24f-d6ee6f633498&page_num=0) points to [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00251764) noting _chiral resolution_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both oxirane carbon atoms are optically active, because both contain 4 different substituents. The left one has a methyl group, a hydrogen atom, the other oxirane carbon atom and the oxygen atom from the oxirane ring. The other oxirane carbon has the following substituents: a hydrogen, an ethyl group, the oxirane oxigen and the other oxirane carbon. I assume the author of the textbook made the mistake to count the oxirane ring as one functional group, and overlooked that this one functional group functions as two substituents.

Comment: Maybe the author of the book forgot the non visible H atoms.